# beamer-lualatex: Option clash for package fontspec when setting up its encoding

Tags: beamer, luatex, fontspec, beamer-metropolis

When compiling a beamer document using lualatex, I use `fontspec` package without problems. However, when setting up its encoding as in this MWE, I always get this error

> Option clash for package fontspec

should I load `fontspec` without specifying the encoding, or is there something missing here?

```
\documentclass[lualatex]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages,blindtext}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \blindtext
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[lualatex]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages,blindtext}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \blindtext
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

should be ok. When running `lualatex` fontspec is already loaded with the `tuenc` definition file:

> [...]
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)(load
>   luc:
>   [...]

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I found a lot of answers loading `fontspec` with `lualatex`, so your answer implies that such a practice is useless.

Comment: no, not in general!  The style `metropolis` loads `fontspec` and `fontspec` itself uses by default `tuenc.def`.

Comment: Ohh I see. Many thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 3):

Internally the metropolis theme does the following for xetex or luatex:

```
\@ifpackageloaded{fontspec}{
  \PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
}{
  \RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}
}
```

This means, just switching the order you load your packages (`fontspec` before `metropolis`) will remove the option-clash error. However, as pointed out by [Ulrike Fischer in her comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366990/beamer-lualatex-option-clash-for-package-fontspec-when-setting-up-its-encoding/366995?noredirect=1#comment904872_366995), passing options to an already loaded package does not make much sense either. So you could:

```
\documentclass[lualatex]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages,blindtext}

\PassOptionsToPackage{tuenc}{fontspec}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \blindtext
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You didn't try ... loading a package with two distinct option sets always give a clash, regardless of the order. Beside this: the code metropolis is senseless, you can't pass an option to a package that has already been loaded.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did try. If the package is already loaded, the branch `\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}` of the if will be used. I did not test if this has any effect, but it won't create an option clash. Worst case, `tuenc` won't be passed to fontspec, but per Herberts answer, it seems to be used anyway.

Comment: Oh sorry, I had a local version in my path. But the code is senseless nevertheless ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree, just removing the line should have the same effect

Comment: @UlrikeFischer edited my answer a bit :) Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to ask something a bit off-topic: when do I need to specify `fontspec` encodings instead of just loading it ?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou No idea